# How to save and display selected value from drop down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an attribute in my articles model called 'title'.

I can put the below in a form for my new.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <%= form.label :title %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :title %>
</p>
```

This generates an input box for the user to type a title.
In my show.html.erb I can display the title with:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>
```

Are drop down lists not the same?
I started by adding an attribute to my articles model and migrating it:

```
rails generate migration add_dropdown_attribute_to_articles programlang:string
```

I can place this in the my new.html.erb form:

```
<p>
  <%= form.select :programlang, [['Ruby','ruby'],['Python','python']]%>
</p>
```

I want to save one of the two options the user chooses and display it in show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Language:</strong>
  <%= @article.programlang %>
</p>
```

I thought this would display either 'Ruby' or 'Python' as the users choice but this is not working.
There are no errors but no values are displayed in the show.html.erb

I'm just wondering if I actually have to do something more for this to work.  I figured that if can get
user input from a box and display it, I could do the same with a drop down list.

I've been trying to find a guide that explains this but they are all wanting to do more complicated actions with the
values in the drop down list.  I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible.  Do I need to add 'Python' and 'Ruby' to a seed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<%= form.select :programlang, options_for_select([['Ruby', 'ruby'], ['Python', 'python']], (@article.programlang)), { include_blank: 'None'}, class: "" %>
```

In controller

```
def article_params 
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :description, :keyword, :syntax, :programlang) 
end
```

Comment: I'm playing with it.  I'm currently getting:    app/views/articles/new.html.erb:42: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'

Comment: `:programlang` to from `: programlang`

Comment: I don't get an error but it does the same thing as before and does not display on my show.html.erb

Comment: *edit* I checked my database and I do not see it in there.

Comment: are you allowing the attribute in strong params

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new with this.  Are you talking about adding the <strong> </strong> tag around <%= @article.programlang %> ?  or do I need to do something else?

Comment: The database shows that it saved programlang as "nil"... => #<Article id: 9, title: "Ruby Code", text: "Here is a snippet of Ruby.", created_at: "2017-10-06 04:44:57", updated_at: "2017-10-06 04:44:57", description: "Test for ruby code.", keyword: "ruby", syntax: "class GPGoptions\r\ninclude Option\r\n\r\n  def Option.f...", programlang: nil>

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156065/questions-46598192 join here

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the basic and it will work

```
<%= form.select :programlang, options_for_select([['Ruby','ruby'],['Python','python']]) %>
```

Or for selected option

```
<%= form.select :programlang, options_for_select(['Ruby','Python'], 'Ruby') %>
```